# Styling definition lists horizontally with term ontop of definition

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I have a piece of code, say

```
<dl>
   <dt>term 1</dt>
   <dd>My data</dd>
   <dt>term 1</dt>
   <dd>My data</dd>
   <dt>term 1</dt>
</dl>
```

Using css(3), how would I achieve lining them up so that the order was like so?

```
Definition    Definition    ......
Term          Term
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they have a fixed width and height, or if they don't need to wrap to the next line, it should be possible with a little hacking:

http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/hN34S/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that without an additional wrapping element. Here is a really good site for styling definition lists: http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/definition/

Comment: Fortunately, nothing is impossible, ESP using CSS3 and HTML5!

Comment: @iRedMedia - If you have a solution that doesn't require additional wrapper elements, and can handle variable sized data, I'd love to see it. I consider myself to be pretty competent when it comes to HTML/CSS/JavaScript, and without fixing the sizes of the elements, or using a wrapper, I don't see how it can be done.